# In PHP Trying to Get Array Foreach into XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I Have an Array that I want a foreach to display the Key and Value as XML. The Page is coming up with `<$value>` and that is it? Any Ideas? Thank You!

```
$XML_a = array ("Ticket_ID" => "12343456");
    $query = "";
 $string_top = 
"<varcor_api>
    <response>";
       foreach ($XML_a as $key => $value) {
          $query .= "<" . $key . "><" . $value . "></" . $key . ">";
       }
$string_bottom = "
    </response>
</varcor_api>
";
    echo $string_top . $query . $string_bottom;
```

Comment: You did you try closing you your tags for the value like `"<$value />"`? Also i would really use `DOMDocument` for this....

Comment: Is this "<" . $key . "><" . $value . "></" . $key . ">" supposed to be "<" . $key . ">" . $value . "</" . $key . ">"

Comment: Why manually codify an XML document instead of using a [PHP library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/487629/59087) or a [database call](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/XML_Support)?

Comment: Dave Jarvis this is going to be an API Call, I am using MariaDB and PHP to get the Ticket_ID then generating a SimpleXMLElement to display the XML, Which it works now. Thank You Dave Goten I know better then to have <> for the Value of the XML Element. Appreciate It!

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea to concatenate XML strings into XML structure. Instead, use Array to XML conversion algorithm - see [Convert array to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152176/convert-an-array-to-xml-or-json) and [How to convert array to SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml).